# Reading and printing an html from local disk useing only built in fuctions of python

Tags: python, html, text, printing

I have searched and searched but have have hit a dead end my normal policy is to try looking and only when I've hit a wall ask question I am learning python for school and I have an assignment I need to finish but I can't figure out how now I'm not asking anyone to do my home work for me but maybe someone can explain what coding I'm missing or what in not understanding

I am taking a local saved html file and I'm trying to get python to read it and display and print the text in the python shell only in a simular format as it appers if you open the html in txtpad however it must use only the tools and libraries that come standard with python any help that can be offered I would greatly appreciate it

Here is the code I have

```
    Import re
    html = open("index.html").read()
    text = re.sub("<.*?>", "\n", html)
    print(text)
```

so this causes the text to look like this

```
    "title


     body

     body

     body

     body


     end"
```

i would like it to look like this

```
    "title
     body
     body
     body
     body
     end"
```

but if i remove the "\n" it looks like

```
    "title      body     body     body
     body      end"
```

so that is why i am stuck

Comment: What did your searching reveal, and why did it not work for you?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Well I'm not in front of may pc to explain the exact code I have but I will try my best and thank you for a response I found out how to read and remove html tags and print the information in plain text but it comes out looking like a single line this "this is the title then info in line one thin info in line two then info in line 3" what I need is "title info then the info one line one on the next line ECT"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
    f=f.read()
    print(f)
```

Comment: what didnt work? it does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: well it dose read and print but however it still doesnt print in the format i need it to be